# Is declaring the size (number of elements) of dummy aguments in Fortran bad practice

Tags: fortran, gfortran, dummy-variable

Consider the following code

```
program main
  implicit none

  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: a
  allocate(a(2))

  call test(a,a)

contains
  subroutine test(a1, a2)
    integer, dimension(3), intent(in) :: a1
    integer, dimension(:), intent(in) :: a2

    write(*,*) size(a1,dim=1), size(a2,dim=1)
  end subroutine test

end program main
```

Gfortran compiles this without an error. The output is `3 2`. As you can see, declaring the size of the dummy argument impairs the ability of the program to see the size of the actual argument.

Imagine the consequences if the `intent` was `inout`. It would have cause unexpected and random run-time errors, depending on the part of the memory that is overwritten by the function. This kind of error is really hard to debug.

1. Is this the expected behaviour or is it something that should be fixed in the compiler?
2. If this is the expected behaviour, isn't declaring the size of a dummy argument a bad practice? Should we, as a rule, use `:` or `0:` and check the array size explicitly?

Comment: Do you know the various important differences between assumed-shape and explicit-shape dummy arguments? If so, do you care about this question for the very specific case of your example, or more widely?

Comment: The linked question differs in that the number of elements of the dummy is itself an argument (rather than constant here), but beyond that much holds. If that question doesn't cover what you want to know, please edit your question to focus on specific aspects.

Comment: (To be explicit about 1.: this is a programming error, and one that isn't the compiler's responsibility to detect. There are cases and compiler options which may allow run or compile time detection.)

Comment: I read the linked question and  your answer to it. It was very informative. But the first resteiction in your list isn't observed here. The code wouldn't compile if `a` was not allocatable.

Comment: Do you mean "an actual argument associated with an explicit shape array must have at least as many elements as the dummy argument"? An allocatable `a` hinders the compiler's ability to detect that violation at compile time, yes.

Comment: Yes. So to rephrase my question, should explicit shape arrays be avoided unless there is a good reason (what?) for it?

Comment: Many people would say to avoid explicit shape dummies if you can. There are times when they are useful instead of assumed shape and these come from the differences covered elsewhere (such as implicit interface, matching other ranks, or if you only care about those three elements - cross products come to mind). In other cases there's simply opinion ("assumed shape dummies should be used because they are Fortran 90 rather than Fortran 77").